# JavaScript URL Decode function

Tags: javascript, jquery, urlencode, urldecode

What's the best JavaScript URL decode utility?  Encoding would be nice too and working well with jQuery is an added bonus.

Comment: Did you check `encodeURIComponent` and `decodeURIComponent`?

Comment: is that really the same thing?

Comment: @Gumbo: the same thing as URL encoding and URL decoding - http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

Answer (score 220, accepted):

I've used [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and [decodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) too.

Comment: thanks guys!  looks like the right answer, but Gumbo answered this first..  I feel like he deserves the credit

Comment: This is an incomplete answer.  See the urlDecode() implementation below by @anshuman.

Comment: Nice but it didn't remove '+' signs. @anshuman's answer worked best for me

Comment: Doesn't work with spaces which are represented with ++++

Answer (score 239):

Here is a complete function (taken from [PHPJS](http://phpjs.org/functions/urldecode:572)):

```
function urldecode(str) {
   return decodeURIComponent((str+'').replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
}
```

Comment: +1: this is the true urldecode, handles the case of space being encoded as +, thanks a lot

Comment: This is what I needed to use when the data was encoded with PHP's urlencode() function.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is decoding + as %20, not as space - that's not really what you wanted here, is it? You'd want the space, not another version of an encoded character... no?

Comment: @ChrisMoschini: No, this is correct because the replace occurs before the decode call.

Comment: @lfaraone I see - so the goal of that tidbit of code is to ensure plus signs come out as spaces in the output instead of being left be as plusses by decodeURIComponent.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is a perfect way to handle strings in jquery which have been previously urlencoded with php, just what I needed!!

Comment: This method is also better if the string was encoded with `HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode` (which encodes spaces as "+"s) instead of `HttpServerUtility.UrlPathEncode` (which encodes spaces as "%20") in C#.NET, as well.

Comment: if, in PHP, you json_encode() a value and then put that in a cookie with setcookie(), you may need to do this before you JSON.parse() it. even though you didnt explicitly urlencode() it.

Comment: Are the plus signes the only thing that needs to be replaced ?

Comment: @momo Other things taken care by decodeURIComponent.

Comment: @anshuman What if I need to decode what I encoded using `urldecode`? Will `encodeURIComponent` work just fine or will I need to alter the input as you did with `urldecode`?

Answer (score 9):

```
decodeURIComponent(mystring);
```

you can get passed parameters by using this bit of code:

```
//parse URL to get values: var i = getUrlVars()["i"];
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

Or this one-liner to get the parameters:

```
location.search.split("your_parameter=")[1]
```

Comment: You should use `window.location.search` instead.

Answer (score 9):

Use this

```
unescape(str);
```

I'm not a great JS programmer, tried all, and this worked awesome!

Comment: Cool answer, but looks like it's [obsoleted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FFunctions#escape_and_unescape_functions(Obsoleted_above_JavaScript_1.5)) in favor of `decodeURIComponent()` due to poor support of non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 3):

```
//How decodeURIComponent Works

function proURIDecoder(val)
{
  val=val.replace(/\+/g, '%20');
  var str=val.split("%");
  var cval=str[0];
  for (var i=1;i<str.length;i++)
  {
    cval+=String.fromCharCode(parseInt(str[i].substring(0,2),16))+str[i].substring(2);
  }

  return cval;
}

document.write(proURIDecoder(window.location.href));
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. decodeURIComponent did not work for me (Malformed URI sequence).

Answer (score 2):

If you are responsible for encoding the data in PHP using urlencode, PHP's rawurlencode works with JavaScript's decodeURIComponent without needing to replace the + character.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I used:

**In JavaScript:**

```
var url = "http://www.mynewsfeed.com/articles/index.php?id=17";
var encoded_url = encodeURIComponent(url);

var decoded_url = decodeURIComponent(encoded_url);
```

**In PHP:**

```
$url = "http://www.mynewsfeed.com/articles/index.php?id=17";
$encoded_url = url_encode(url);

$decoded_url = url_decode($encoded_url);
```

You can also try it online here: http://www.mynewsfeed.x10.mx/articles/index.php?id=17

Answer (score 0):

```js
var uri = "my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
console.log(encodeURI(uri));
```

Answer (score 0):

`decodeURIComponent()` is fine, but you never want ot use `encodeURIComponent()` directly.  This fails to escape reserved characters like `*`, `!`, `'`, `(`, and `)`.  Check out [**RFC3986**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), where this is defined, for more info on that.  The Mozilla Developer Network documentation gives both a good explanation and a solution.  Explanation...

> To be more stringent in adhering to RFC 3986 (which reserves !, ', (, ), and *), even though these characters have no formalized URI delimiting uses, the following can be safely used:

Solution...

```
function fixedEncodeURIComponent(str) {
  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function(c) {
    return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
  });
}
```

In case you're not sure, check out a [**good, working demo at JSBin.com**](https://jsbin.com/cifeciw/edit?html,js,console).  Compare this with a [**bad, working demo at JSBin.com using `encodeURIComponent()` directly**](https://jsbin.com/nogober/edit?html,js,console).

Good code results:

> `thing%2athing%20thing%21`

Bad code results from `encodeURIComponent()`:

> `thing*thing%20thing!`