# How do I make this string normal in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=endscreen&amp;NR=1&amp;v=Ahha3Cqe_fk
```

For some reason, the string is that. How can I change the `&amp;` and make them real symbols?

Do I URL encode or decode?

Comment: url = url.replace(/&/, "&amp;")

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript URL Decode function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292914/javascript-url-decode-function)

Comment: @MyStupidSelf: Ugh it's getting late. Please disregard the close vote.

Comment: Just a wee note: that's still a perfectly valid URL! &amp; is a perfectly cromulent HTML character entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("<div>", {html: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=endscreen&amp;NR=1&amp;v=Ahha3Cqe_fk"}).text()`

or

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=endscreen&amp;NR=1&amp;v=Ahha3Cqe_fk";
div.firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url=str_replace("&amp;","&",$url);
```

It has nothing to do with url encoding. &amp; is an HTML entity of the & symbol.

Pretty much the same deal in JS

```
url.replace("&amp;","&");
```

Comment: So yeah I did get carried away with my PHP.

Comment: I'll offset the negative vote, this is much better than the horde of completely irrelevant url decode answers. You want `url.replace(/&amp;/g,"&");` though

Answer (score 0):

Create a DOM element, assign above encoded string to its `innerHTML` and return `nodeValue`.

That will be a more robust solution. If you simply want to tackle this one entity an explicit `.replace()` will do the trick: `url.replace(/&amp;/g, "&")`.