# How to decode a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

This isn't working for me:

```
var foo = "Collection%3A 9 Bad Interviews With Former GOP Presidential Candidates";

console.log(decodeURI(foo));
```

It outputs:

```
Collection%3A 9 Bad Interviews With Former GOP Presidential Candidates
```

That's not correct, if you enter the foo string on a site like this:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

It shows the right output, which is:

```
Collection: 9 Bad Interviews With Former GOP Presidential Candidates
```

How to properly decode the string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript URL Decode function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292914/javascript-url-decode-function)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Differences between [decodeURI](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp) and [decodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp)

The main differences are:

[encodeURI](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp) is intended to be used on the full URI.

[encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) is intended to be used on .. well .. URI components that is any part that lies between separators (; / ? : @ & = + $ , #).

So, in [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) these separators are encoded also because they are regarded as text and not special characters.

Now back to the difference between the decode functions, each function decodes strings generated by its corresponding encode counterpart taking care of the semantics of the special characters and their handling.

so in your case [decodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp) does the job

Answer (score 7):

Use [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent):

```
var decoded = decodeURIComponent(foo);
```

`decodeURI` has some issues as you are seeing. `decodeURIComponent` is the best practice tool for this job.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
unescape("Collection%3A 9 Bad Interviews With Former GOP Presidential Candidates")
```

Answer (score 1):

The URI `decodeURI()` expects actually looks like this:

> Collection:%209%20Bad%20Interviews%20With%20Former%20GOP%20Presidential%20Candidates

Check out [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/En2JK/1/) demonstrating what I mean. You'll want [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) instead.