# Encode/Decode string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

i have string, have got from database, it's equal `Ivory Coast(Cote D'Ivoire)`, then this string displayed with javaScript. And get next result: `Ivory Coast(Cote D&#39;Ivoire)`. The `'` character was converted! How to resolve this problev in JavaScript?

P.S. I haven't written code for you because i don't think it can help you in this case! My question clear without it.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decode a string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692071/how-to-decode-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835317/unicode-value-uxxxx-to-character-in-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unescape HTML entities in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript)

Comment: Are you using server-side javascript?

Answer (score 0):

[Unescape HTML entities in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript).

This link help me! In my case I have wrote the next code:

```
$('#messageText').html(message).text();
```

where `#messageText` a div container, that must contain a message, `message` my string `Ivory Coast(Cote D'Ivoire)`. It work fine!

P.S. Thanks everybody for helping! :)