# Javascript ajax how to show just a value of array

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am newbie in javascript and need some help :( I am simply using post api in my html page like this

```
varsettings = {
  "url": "https://credimax.gateway.mastercard.com/api/nvp/version/54",
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Cookie": "TS01f8f5b8=0163461fdde5ee3588241a8b83c8806a36a236cc1484715206aeee58f05ff4acc21bff27c0f22f45d8027bdfa3ef1b330efc711746"
  },
  "data": {
    "apiOperation": "CREATE_CHECKOUT_SESSION",
    "apiPassword": "asdasdasdsad",
    "apiUsername": "merchant.sadasda",
    "merchant": "asdasda",
    "interaction.operation": "AUTHORIZE",
    "order.id": "121312327",
    "order.amount": "0.01",
    "order.currency": "BHD"
  }



};
$.ajax(varsettings).done(function(response) {
  console.log(response);


});
```

Its showing responsei n console correctly like this

```
merchant=E10561950&result=SUCCESS&session.id=SESSION0002247374303I6654970F90&session.updateStatus=SUCCESS&session.version=18a5ad4401&successIndicator=5f04c5071d2f46fd
```

I want to just console the session.id from response how can i do this ?

i try with with `console.log(response.session.id)` but its not showing

Comment: maybe it helps:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48980380/returning-data-from-axios-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48980380/returning-data-from-axios-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
<script>
    $.ajax(varsettings).done(function (response) {
        let items = response.split('&');
        let sessionIDText = items[2];
        let sessionIDParts = sessionIDText.split('=');
        let sessionID = sessionIDParts[1]
        console.log(sessionID);
    });
</script>
```

or simply :

```
    sessionID = response.split('&')[2].split('=')[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have received a string back from the server that needs to be decoded into an object before you can work with it. Try `obj = decodeURIComponent(response)` and see if you can work with the resulting `obj`

Comment: i try and then console obj its same hot show session.id from this obj ?

Comment: maybe try just decodeURI(result)  ...sorry I am on a phone and can't test right now but look at this thread... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692071/how-to-decode-a-string-in-javascript