# special characters stored in cookies are not retrieved properly using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, html, cookies

I created a code that stores some of my keywords to a cookie, but I was encountering an issue with accented characters like ä,Ä etc, special characters for other languages.

it is supported by my local machine because I can retrieve it using other methods except for the ones stored in cookies.

I also retrieve this cookie keywords by jquery but it seems that I am getting the incorrect decoded values.

any thoughts?

thank you. very much.

Comment: how does the "incorrect" string you get back look?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is similar to the problem mentioned in the pos below, then it looks like url encoding is applied to the values being stored in the cookie.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478797/storing-special-characters-in-cookies-using-jquery-plugin

You can 'reverse' this by decoding the value. This is discussed in the following post.

[JavaScript URL Decode function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292914/javascript-url-decode-function)