# passing and retrieving Latin Character in URL query string

Tags: javascript, html

I am having two **HTML**s `step1.html` and `step2.html` and I am passing latin value(`envían` )from `step1.html` to s`tep2.html` via URL query string by having the to be passed value(`envían`) in input field value(which is in hidden state in `step1.html`.

I am getting the value of the query string parameter in `step2.html` using some utility function and I am displaying the value in one textbox but i got the value in textbox as different from the value passed see the screenshot.

[image]

Got encoded value for `í`, help me to get the same value `í` in `step2.html` also.

**EDIT:** One disadvantage is `step2.html` is twitter.com, there i cannot do any decoding. see the screenshot below
[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

### **STEP1.html**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="">
        <form action="step2.html">
            <input type="submit" value="click to submit"/>

            <input type="hidden" name="val" value="envían" />
        </form>
    </div>  
</body>
```

### **Step2.html**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
    <script>

    var QueryString = function () {
      // This function is anonymous, is executed immediately and 
      // the return value is assigned to QueryString!
      var query_string = {};
      var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
      var vars = query.split("&");
      for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
            // If first entry with this name
        if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
          query_string[pair[0]] = pair[1];
            // If second entry with this name
        } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
          var arr = [ query_string[pair[0]], pair[1] ];
          query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
            // If third or later entry with this name
        } else {
          query_string[pair[0]].push(pair[1]);
        }
      } 
        return query_string;
    } ();

    function fngetval(){
        var val=QueryString.val;

        document.getElementById("status").value=val;
    }

    </script>

    <style>

    </style>
</head>

<body onload="fngetval();">
    <div class="">
        <textarea id="status" name="status" ></textarea>
    </div>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have the `í` in a URL, thus why it is encoded into `%ED`.

You can either 1) use a `POST` form instead of the default `GET`. or 2) decode the value of the `val` variable. See this Stack Overflow question: [JavaScript URL Decode function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292914/javascript-url-decode-function).

Comment: Thanks For the help. but my limitation is I am passing this query string value to twitter website, see the attached screenshot(see in the question now i edited the question), there i cannot do any decode process.

Comment: @MohamedHussain Are you able to use the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/)? This is really on Twitter's end, as other encoded symbols (such as `%20`, `%22`, `%3F`, etc.) are correctly decoded.

Comment: Thanks for enlighten me on Twitter API.