# Decoding in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, decode

I'm trying to decode a string and insert it into a new string, but it just **won't work**. 
I tried **unescape** and **decodeURIComponent**.

What am I doing wrong? Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qc1TMrEZucP7RhFjwg15?p=preview).

This is the code:

```
var str = "2015 &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160; &#58;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160; alle";
alert(unescape(str));
```

I prefer to do it in AngularJS.

Comment: Did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292914/javascript-url-decode-function ?

Comment: Those are HTML entities, not URL encoding. All `&#160;` are just no-break spaces. And the `&#58;` is a `:`.

Comment: Oh ok thanks! I'll go and search for HTML entities decoding.

Comment: unescape works on hex numbers, e.g. `%A7`. you don't have hex digits, you have html entities: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery

Comment: You could decode it with `str.replace(/&#(\d+);/g, function(t, c){return String.fromCharCode(c);});`.

Comment: @David Uhh.. nope not really he is doing it with Jquery and so far I know I didn't ask for any Jquery?

Comment: @Goldenowner: There's more than one answer to that question.  Try scrolling down.

Comment: @David Ok sorry, I got it now and it works thank you!