# my emails display %40 instead of @ sign when i submit form

Tags: html

I created a form that displays the results in another html page but the `@` sign is displayed as `%40` in the new page. This is my code below. Can someone help out?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var url = document.location.href,
        params = url.split('?')[1].split('&'),
        data = {}, tmp;
    for (var i = 0, l = params.length; i < l; i++) {
         tmp = params[i].split('=');
         data[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
    }
    document.getElementById('email-display').innerHTML = data.Email;

}
</script>
```

Comment: You need to URL-decode the value.

Comment: **1.** You need to URL decode the parameters. **2.** Your use of `innerHTML` for unfiltered user submitted values is an XSS vulnerability. Consider using `textContent` instead.

Comment: Why are you handling this with client-side scripting instead of doing server-side? When the HTML form is submitted, the server could easily decode the URL parameters and return a new HTML page that has the email field pre-populated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The URL query component is encoded. You are not fully decoding it. `%40` is the encoded form of `@`. Technically,   `@` is not required to be encoded in the query component, but your server is doing so.

After you split the query data on `&` and `=`, you need to decode the resulting  substrings by replacing the `%XX` hex sequences with the corresponding bytes, and then converting the resulting bytes to string characters based on whatever charset your server uses (usually utf-8, but not always).

Read [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), in particular [Section 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1) and [Section 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4).

Comment: I really didn't get a think.. I am lost. Can you please explain more or you can please help correct the javascript. I am not really good with javascript

Comment: See [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/) and [JavaScript URL Decode function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292914/).