# How to decode html form values from url in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

In my html page, I have a form tag (`GET`) that has no encoding type, so it would be using

`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default according to this:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp

But then it encodes spaces into `+` signs. For example, when I pass

`a b c & f`, it turns it into

`a+b+c+%26+f` in the url. Then if I do the javascript `decodeURIComponent` function I get

`a+b+c+&+f`, but what javascript function do I call if I want the original string `a b c & f`? I prefer not to hardcode string replaces.

Does anyone know the way to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: May be this is useful.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8649003

Comment: The short answer how to handle this is to replace the + signs with spaces first, then decode the rest of the data. But what you actually need is a query string parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use replace function in javascript after you get string from decodeURIComponent

```
str.replace("+", " ");
or
str.replace(/\+/g, ' ');
```

Comment: I figured this is a way, and you mean `str.replace("+"," ")`, but is this really the best practice way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292914/javascript-url-decode-function   use 202 upvotes answer

Answer (score 0):

There is Jquery Pluggin which you can use. [Here](https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl)

Or look into this [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Update: here's the article I wrote about it one time for HTML Goodies: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/11877_3755006_2

Take a look at the simple `ptq` (parse-the-query) function, one of the library of functions I wrote in 2001.

```
function ptq(s, q) {
  var i, p;
  s = s.replace(/\+/g, ' ').replace(/;/g, '&').split('&');
  q = q || {};
  for (i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
    p = s[i].split('=', 2);
    q[unescape(p[0])] = unescape(p[1]);
  }
  return q;
  }
```

It works even with very old JavaScript versions, and using it is simple:

```
  var q = ptq(location.search.substring(1));
  /* grab query string after the initial "?" delimiter */
```

The properties of `q` will then correspond to any `name=value` pairs defined in the HTML form values submitted to the current URL via a GET request's query string.

For example, if an HTML form contained a field named `name` with contents "Joseph" and if this form is submitted as specified by its `action` attribute to the HTML page `file.html` then the GET request will be "file.html?name=Joseph" and the value of `q.name` will equal the string literal `"Joseph"`.

Some parts of the code, like `escape`/`unescape` have newer and preferred equivalents if later features of JavaScript are available.

Dredging up a later revision of this code, you can also use Boolean parameters in your URLs like "file.html?name=Joseph&secure", although these will never be generated by a browser when submitting an HTML form. It's also easier to use. Just write `q = param();` in your code, similar to Lincoln D. Stein's CGI.pm module syntax.

```
function ptq(q)
{
  /* parse the query */
  /* semicolons are nonstandard but we accept them */
  var x = q.replace(/;/g, '&').split('&'), i, name, t;
  /* q changes from string version of query to object */
  for (q={}, i=0; i<x.length; i++)
  {
    t = x[i].split('=', 2);
    name = unescape(t[0]);
    if (!q[name])
      q[name] = [];
    if (t.length > 1)
    {
      q[name][q[name].length] = unescape(t[1]);
    }
    /* next two lines are nonstandard */
    else
    {
      q[name][q[name].length] = true;
    }
  }
  return q;
}

function param()
{
  return ptq(location.search.substring(1).replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
```

Note that in this new revision all form fields are returned as arrays. This is much more appropriate since the standard allows for multiple form fields with the same name, meaning that the correct the data type for a form field's value is an array of strings.