# How to replace %20 with + in window location href using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#search_result").change(function(){
            str = $(this).val();
            search = str.replace(/%20/g, "+");
            window.location.href = "courses.php?search-result="+search
        });
    });
```

In this code I have a dropdown where I have multiple values and now I want to pass dropdown values in url using window.location.href. Now, values are passing perfectly but I want to replace (%20) with (+). I am using str.replace function but not able to see any changes. So, How can I get my url like.

```
courses.php?search-result=core+java
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? :-)  *"courses.php?search-result=core%20java"* is a totally valid URL as well

Comment: Because I need this @PhilippMaurer :)

Comment: From what you were able to describe, perhaps you want to have it like this:

str.replace(/ /g, '+')

The inital string has actual spaces instead of escaped ones (%20). hence str.replace(/%20/g, "+") does not affect it

Comment: Have look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292914/javascript-url-decode-function#answer-4458580 It 's all about url decoding with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is decoding the url. The answer is given already here: [JavaScript URL Decode function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292914/javascript-url-decode-function#answer-4458580).