# Encode GET value in Javascript

Tags: jquery

I use the following code to get `GET` values from a URL an use them in my jQuery script.

URL-example: `www.example.com/de/product&print=1?option=0?money=CHF%20%202680.%E2%80%93`

```
/* GET VALUES TO SELECT OPTION */
jQuery.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1] || 0;
}

/* GET MONEY VALUE */
var money = jQuery.urlParam('money');
console.log(money);
```

I can get the value money with this code but how can I transform it to "normal-text". The value should be `"CHF 2680.-" and not "CHF%20%202680.%E2%80%93"` so that I can use it in javascript.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292914/javascript-url-decode-function/4458580)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript URL Decode function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292914/javascript-url-decode-function)

Answer (score 1):

There is a global function `decodeURI()` in javascript that takes care of encoded text.

Usage:

```
var money = jQuery.urlParam('money');
var decodedMoney = decodeURI(money)
console.log(decodedMoney);
```

`decodeURI()` replaces each escape sequence in the encoded URI with the actual character that it represents.

Comment: wouldn't it be `console.log(decodedMoney)` to show the value already decoded?