# HttpHeader UTF encoding

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, encoding, http-headers

I need to store messages in different languages in Http Header:

Response Headers

```
Cache-Control   private
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version 3.0
X-Message-Type  Success
X-Message   <p>Token wysÅany</p>
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
Date    Wed, 18 May 2011 12:49:26 GMT
Content-Length  2
```

But, as you can see X-Message looses it's formatting. it should be "Token wysłany". 
Help. thanks

EDIT:
this is what i have:

```
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            var viewData = filterContext.Controller.ViewData;
            var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

            foreach (var messageType in Enum.GetNames(typeof(MessageType)))
            {
                var message = viewData.ContainsKey(messageType)
                                ? (ErrorMessageExtensions.ErrorMessage)viewData[messageType]
                                : null;
                if (message != null) // We store only one message in the http header. First message that comes wins.
                {
                    response.AddHeader("X-Message-Type", messageType);
                    response.AddHeader("X-Message", message.RenderAjax());
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

i'm trying to integrate messaging into my mvc app (like so): http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2011/05/03/keep-your-users-informed-with-asp-net-mvc/  the only problem is that it needs to support multilanguages. What are some other options (or fixes for this solutions that would support other language characters)? thanks

Comment: I got here looking exactly for the same thingy. I'm also using MvcNotification... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem with this very messaging project by Martijn Boland. In my case I needed accented characters that we use in the Brazilian Portuguese language as: é á í ó ã õ, etc...

I did this to solve the problem:

```
response.AddHeader("X-Message", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(message.ToString()));
```

and then in the view page (.cshtml) where you show the message:

```
function displayMessage(message, messageType)
{
    $("#messagewrapper").html('<div class="messagebox ' + messageType.toLowerCase() + '"></div>');

    $("#messagewrapper .messagebox").html(message);

    displayMessages();
}
```

See that I changed from

`$("#messagewrapper .messagebox").text(message);`

to

`$("#messagewrapper .messagebox").html(message);`

That's because now we're getting [entity numbers](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp) ( `HTML` markup ) instead of plain text.

Doing so you won't need that additional decode-jquery-plugin you mention in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out, headers should contain only US-ASCII or ISO-8859-1 characters.

Depending on who is going to read the header, consider `urlencode()` ing the message.

That will make sure you have only ASCII characters in the header. As long as you're in UTF-8 all the way, it will work fine.

Of course, you need to do a `urldecode()` on it so it becomes readable again.

Comment: how would i decode it?? function checkAndHandleMessageFromHeader(request) {
    var msg = request.getResponseHeader('X-Message');
    if (msg) {
        displayMessage(msg, request.getResponseHeader('X-Message-Type'));
    }
}

Comment: @Shane I don't know what the function is to URLDecode data in ASP.net (overlooked that tag) but I'm sure it exists in the basic library.

Answer (score 1):

The [HTTP headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2) use the US-ASCII encoding, so you should avoid sending characters in the headers which are outside of this encoding. The [message body](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.3) can of course use any encoding.

Comment: Is it not theoretically possible, though? According to [this](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), `If a character set other than ISO-8859-1 is used, it MUST be encoded in the warn-text using the method described in RFC 2047 [14].` ... although I personally would just URLencode it and be done with it

Comment: @Pekka, I wouldn't experiment with this. I would always encode so that ASCII is used.

Comment: Darin, how would i add some content to message-body?

Comment: @Shane Km, that's the contents sent by the server. Usually the HTML you see in the browser.

Comment: yes, but how would i add it to my response in filterContext.HttpContext?

Comment: @Shane Km, your question is extremely unclear. What are you trying to achieve? What is the purpose of the action filter? Why are you trying to append HTTP headers?

Comment: i'm trying to integrate messaging into my mvc app (like so): http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2011/05/03/keep-your-users-informed-with-asp-net-mvc/  the only problem is that it needs to support multilanguages. What are some other options? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i figured it out. In order to use other language characters I do the following:

```
response.AddHeader("X-Message", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(message.RenderAjax(), Encoding.UTF8));
```

Then, i use this plugin: http://urldecoderonline.com/javascript-url-decode-jquery-plugin.htm
to urldecode the string.  This generates correct output :).

thanks everyone for help.

Comment: To decode the message you can also use the standard JavaScript function: `decodeURIComponent(msg)`. No need for a plugin. More about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3803742/114029

Answer (score 0):

HttpHeaders can only contain ISO-8859-1 characters (a full list available [here](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/charset/latin1.gif)).

I don't believe there are any work arounds for this.