# Swap + (plus) with space in string

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I decode a URL with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803716/how-can-i-decode-a-url-with-jquery)

Could somebody please help me to take a string (i.e. URL parameter) and remove the +(plus) or %20 to a regular space (" ")?

For example, to change this:

```
"my+string+to+change" or "my%20string%20to%20change"
```

to this:

```
"my string to change"
```

I use a lot of jQuery already, so that would be fine. Or pure javascript if that's easier.

Comment: For what it's worth please see the `decodeURIcomponent` in action here : http://jsfiddle.net/Rxa5C/

Comment: I really don't appreciate being downvoted for this. I disagree that this is an "exact duplicate" and in fact did not get an answer from the linked page. My question is not about a URL but about changing a string.

Answer (score 2):

Use `decodeURIcomponent(stringToDecode)`

Note this is not a jquery feature but a regular javascript function.

Comment: Care to elaborate? EDIT: Nevermind, Ashutosh Jindal answered this, as a comment above. Thanks!