# javascript url decoding doesn't work

Tags: javascript, urldecode

My string is;

```
var str = "Mehmet%2bAli%2b%c3%96zcan";
```

And I want to get string;

```
var strDecoded = "Mehmet Ali Özcan";
```

I tried all of followings;

```
strDecoded = decodeURIComponent(str); // Fails;
strDecoded = decodeURIComponent((str + '').replace(/\+/g, '%20')); // Fails
strDecoded = _decodeURI(str); // Fails


function _decodeURI(str) {
  str = decodeURI(str);
  str = str.replace(/%27/g, "'");
  return str;
}
```

What can I do else to get correct string? any idea?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803716/how-can-i-decode-a-url-with-jquery.

Comment: This is the wrong problem, your problem is how those strings are generated, a space should be `%20`, not a `+` or even `%2b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
decodeURIComponent("Mehmet%2bAli%2b%c3%96zcan").replace(/\++/g, ' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
decodeURIComponent(str.replace(/%2b/g, '%20'));
```